# How to rigify with 2.8

Tags: rigging, rigify

So I am creating a low poly monkey and am trying to rig it for a game. I am new to rigging and trying to figure out how it works. After creating my character's bones, I press rigify and nothing happens. I can't seen to get my meta rig (I think that's what it's called) to show up. The only thing that shows up are the arrows pointing in all directions beneath my character.
Can anyone help me create the meta rig so that I can move my character around???

Here is a [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2aL3r7RO3Tz0yv6j_QuobURfu7) to my project and down below is a screen shot of my project.

[image]

I am trying to get something like this, with all of the blue icons and controls.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For a good tutorial start with the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JSFcSxsaTs

Comment: Totally endorsing this. This video will show you the basic steps from the metarig to the GENERATED RIG. It is important you distinguish between both of these armatures in the bone layers and outliner.

Answer (score 0):

The [rigify addon](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Rigging/Rigify/) is setup to work with an armature that has been configured a specific way, this is made easy by using the premade rigs that the addon supplies. If you want any of the IK/FK rig features, you should start with one of the prebuilt rigs.

The shapes that you refer to are called custom bone shapes and can be manually added to any rig, not just by using the rigify addon. You will find the [viewport display](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/animation/armatures/bones/properties/display.html) options (called display in 2.79) under the bone properties while in pose mode, where you can choose any mesh object to be displayed in place of each bone.

[image: custom bone display properties]

Comment: The viewport display hyperlink redirects to a [page that doesn't exist](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/armatures/bones/properties/display.html) - it was either moved or deleted.